# Repetition in spider result from table

Tags: python, html, scrapy

I'm witting a python spider in scrapy to parse the page and everything works, except the extraction from table. It extract the data from table but repeat it multiple time.

So for the table:

```
<tbody><tr>
      <td><b>Name</b></td>
      <td><b>Role</b></td>
    </tr>
            <tr style="background-color:#C0C0C0; color:Black;">
            <td>Name 1</td>
            <td>No Party</td>
            </tr>
            <tr style="background-color:#C0C0C0; color:Black;">
            <td>Eny</td>
            <td>Party</td>
            </tr>
            <tr style="background-color:#C0C0C0; color:Black;">
            <td>Cory</td>
            <td>Party</td>
            </tr>
</tbody>
```

So I need to grab strings from table  that have second Party, combine them and write as one string 
I will write the parser like this:

```
raw_data['names'] = process_string(", ".join(page.xpath('//tr[td="Party"]/td[1]/text()').extract()))
```

In result I got:

Eny, Cory, Ent, Cory, Eny, Cory, Eny, Cory

So it repeat a correct result 4 times. 
There is no repetition in scrip, other field works perfect so it nothing wrong with scrip, it is just this expression.
I tried different xpath but result are the same. What is different with tables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not an expert in XPath, so here is how it's possible to do that with CSS selectors:

```
names_list = [row.css('td:nth-child(1)::text').extract_first() 
              for row in s.css('tr') 
              if row.css('td:nth-child(2)::text').extract_first() == 'Party']
raw_data['names'] = ', '.join(names_list)
```

Comment: it is not working, may be I made a mistake, but as much as I did some testing it not find anything.

Comment: @alex_mike it works fine for the example you provided. It should return `['Eny', 'Cory']`, right?